# PostgreSQL streaming replication lag for synchronous standbys

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.5

We use PostgreSQL 9.5 in a master + synchronous hot-standby setup, i.e., using `synchronous_commit = on` and using `synchronous_standby_names='*'`.

Consequently, the standby has `sync_state = sync` in the master's `pg_stat_replication_table`.

We also use [postgres_exporter](https://github.com/wrouesnel/postgres_exporter), which [uses](https://github.com/lovoo/postgres_exporter/blob/master/postgres_exporter.go) the following statement to extract the system's replication lag from the master's stats.

```
SELECT *, pg_current_xlog_location(),
       pg_xlog_location_diff(pg_current_xlog_location(), replay_location)::float
FROM pg_stat_replication;
```

**Question**: Does the above call to `pg_xlog_location_diff` always return `0` in a synchronous setup, or are there any cases when there is a measurable replication lag?

To my understanding, if the above statement shows a lag, it means that the master has committed a transaction without waiting for the standby, which should never happen in a synchronous setup.

Note that we moreover use replication slots, have setup the cluster using [`repmgr`](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/repmgr), and do not override `synchronous_commit` locally for individual transactions.

Answer (score 1):

The pg_xlog_location_diff within your query may  return more than 0.

There are three writing timing of WAL data to WAL segment file: 1) When a transaction is committed, 2) When WAL buffer is filled up, 3) When WAL writer process writes periodically (default is 200 milliseconds).

And basic sequence of streaming replication is shown below:

1. (master) Write WAL data.
2. (master) Send WAL data to a slave.
3. (slave) Receive WAL data and replay it.
4. (slave) Return some information (e.g. replay location, receive location, flushed location.)

I show an extreme example to clarify the problem. If you run a long transaction to insert huge data, master continues to send WAL data  till the transaction is committed.  When you issue your query during the period from 2 to 3, `pg_current_xlog_location()` returns the current location whereas `replay_location` returns the previous replay location, `pg_xlog_location_diff(pg_current_xlog_location(), replay_location)` therefore returns more than 0.

Other case is the following: The configuration parameter `max_standby_*_delay` is enable and a conflict occurs, your standby suspends replaying WAL data, therefore `pg_xlog_location_diff()` returns more than 0.

(Both of examples are *logical* extreme cases.)

In any case, I think your problem does not depend on whether replication mode is sync or async. The difference between sync and async is that the master confirms a synchronous slave commits transactions or not.
Your problem is related to general sequence of WAL data sending and replaying, but is not depend on the synchronous mode.

(Consider how a long transaction is committed in synchronous mode. I discussed what happens when your query is issued  during the period from 2 to 3 (it's very short period) in the streaming replication sequence I showed. I did not discussed when transaction is committed because it is not essential of the answer, i think.)

Comment: I think you are missing some details how WAL is handled and exposed to pg_xlog* functions at the master when using a `sync` standby. As far as I have now found out, the master will not expose the lastest (pending) WAL record unless the `sync` standby has confirmed it. I figured out that the query can be changed to use the `flush_location`, in which case to result is always `0` in our system.

Comment: Does the system then work as follows? 1) the master always "commits locally" and thus buffers + later writes WAL data, but 2) [does not "confirm the commit to the client"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/warm-standby.html#SYNCHRONOUS-REPLICATION-CONFIG), until 3) the `sync` standby has durably written (flushed) the WAL data and 4) confirmed the write to the master. In this case, the master must 5) ensure that any "unconfirmed" already written "local commit" (after standby failure + client timeout + transaction abort) is rolled back on the master, which creates new WAL data.

Comment: I rewrote all. Consider a long transaction. Your question does not depend on whether replication mode is sync or async principally. I recommend to read source code directly to understand how streaming replication works.